# C++ weird rounding when decimal passed into function

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and messing around with functions. I have two cpp files and one header. One of my cpp files is main.cpp where the following code is:

```
a->change(42.57);
```

I then have another cpp where the following code for change is:

```
bool Student::change(float mark)
```

and then the header where the following code is:

```
bool change(float mark);
```

When I pass the float in, it is 42.57. However, after it is passed in it suddendly chnages to 42.5699997. Could someone please explain why this happens?

Comment: what happens when you look at the value without passing it to any function? How are you inspecting it anyhow?

Comment: Because 42.57 cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point.

Comment: @SergeBallesta It's not "broken" at all.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Absolutely. It's no more broken than expecting something like `int n = 1.1` to set `n` to anything other than 1.

Comment: @Bathsheba Or calling your notepad "broken" because it failed to properly hold all the decimal places of the number ⅓ when you wrote it out.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: It was a joke of course hence the `;-)`. But you are right on one point some could really think that its is so I will try to avoid to say it now (and I have deleted the comment)

Comment: The **text** that represents the value is `42.57`. Text has to be converted to a value. Don’t skip that step in your analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`42.57` is a `double` type. (The nearest `double` is 42.57000000000000028421709430404007434844970703125).

Use `42.57f` for a `float` type. (The nearest `float` is 42.56999969482421875).

Both therefore are approximations (the `float` is a looser approximation than the `double`) but at least your debugger will display the `float` more appropriately.